How do I know if a journal was indexed in ESCI on a specific date in the past?
There is information for journals in the Scopus database as follows "Years currently covered by Scopus:from 2017 to 2024". In this way, we can learn the date the journal has been in this database. I would like to get the same information from the ESCI. But I could not find this information. Is there a way to learn the year the journal has been in the ESCI?

Did you ask ESCI?

@WolfgangBangerth Yes.

Web of Science shows for which period of years a journal has been indexed, but I'm not clear on whether it reliably updates which index the journal was collected in for each year or if just the most recent index is given. I also don't know of good example journals to check this for.
